# How to prove that a map is well-defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $\varphi \colon \mathbb{Z} / (p_1^{\alpha_1} \dotsm p_k^{\alpha_k}) \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / p_1^{\alpha_1} \mathbb{Z} \times \dotsb \times \mathbb{Z} / p_k^{\alpha_k} \mathbb{Z}$ be defined by
$$
  x +  (p_1^{\alpha_1} \dotsm p_k^{\alpha_k}) \mathbb{Z}
  \mapsto
  (x + p_1^{\alpha_1} \mathbb{Z}, \dotsc, x + p_k^{\alpha_k} \mathbb{Z}) \,.
$$

I want to prove well-definedness of the map in the above question:

I know the general way of proving well-definedness of a map where we take two distinct elements in the domain and equate them to each other and arrive at that their images are equal.

I am a little bit confused here in this map, I do not know how to do this because of the primes I have. Could anyone show me the details of this proof please?

Comment: If you know fundamental theorem on homomorphism, this well-definedness is induced by the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry for my bad English.)

Remark; we don't need primeness for this well-definedness. But if we want to proof that this map is bijective, this condition is required.
So I explain  the case for integers $n_1,\dots,n_k$. (your case is $n_i=p_i^{\alpha_i}$).

If you take two representaions $x,y$ which are equal in $\mathbb{Z}/(n_1\dots n_k)\mathbb{Z}$, then $x-y \in (n_1\cdots n_k)\mathbb{Z}$ i.e. there is a integer $c$ s.t. $x-y=cn_1\cdots n_k$.
So $x-y$ is divisible by $n_i$ for all $1\le i\le k$. It means $x=y$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n_i\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Suggest you change your word "devised" [which doesn't have a common meaning] to the word "divisible", which if done makes your statement there true.

Comment: But how this can be interpreted in terms of the function definition I gave above, I do not see this. I do not see how you arrived at $\varphi (x) = \varphi (y),$ could you please explain this?

Comment: Now $x=y$ is true for all term, so $\phi$ is well-defined. Do you understand this explanation?

Comment: Yeah, I think because the other term is the same in the image of any two elements .... right?

Comment: Now for all $i$,   $x+n_i\mathbb{Z}=y+n_i\mathbb{Z}$, so $(x+n_1\mathbb{Z},\dots,x+n_k\mathbb{Z})=(y+n_1\mathbb{Z},\dots,y+n_k\mathbb{Z})$.